# How to setup `react-native-web` after `react-native init`

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I get several errors after following the guide on [react-rative-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/b84e3b938aff873279fb5618a77e488b128054e1/packages/website/guides/getting-started.md).

I first created a new project: `react-native init test --version 0.55.4`

Then I installed the dependencies:

```
yarn add --dev babel-loader url-loader webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server babel-plugin-react-native-web
yarn add react react-dom react-native-web
```

copied the [index.web.js](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/b84e3b938aff873279fb5618a77e488b128054e1/packages/website/guides/getting-started.md#client-side-rendering) and [web/webpack.config.js](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/b84e3b938aff873279fb5618a77e488b128054e1/packages/website/guides/getting-started.md#web-packaging-for-existing-react-native-apps)

After executing the command:

```
webpack-dev-server -d --config ./web/webpack.config.js --inline --hot --colors
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR in ./index.web.js
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    Error: Cannot find module 'react-art'
```

OK. So I installed the (optional?) module `yarn add react-art`

The next run printed:

```
ERROR in ./index.web.js
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    Error: Plugin 0 specified in "base" provided an invalid property of "createElement"
```

Now I don't know what to do. How can I fix this error (and maybe the following)?

Comment: can you show your `index.web.js`

Comment: Its easier to create a reactjs app, then add `react-native-web` which works the same, but is easier installation.

Comment: @SGhaleb linked the files.
You mean with `npx create-react-app test`? Is it easy to add react-native (Android and iOS) after?

Comment: Yes, I have the same setup where I test web, android and ios. But if you are planning to deploy react-native app, then I would just copy and past the src folders into a new react-native.

Comment: If you install packages and get an error, then you may need to add them to `web.config.js` like this`const babelLoaderConfiguration = { include: [ path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons')]}`